# Why does the author wrap tasksRepository.refreshTasks() with viewModelScope.launch?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

The function of `tasksRepository.refreshTasks()` is to insert data from remote server to local DB, it's a time consuming operation.

In `class TasksViewModel`, `asksRepository.refreshTasks()` is wrapped with `viewModelScope.launch{}`, it means launch and careless.

1: How can I guarantee `tasksRepository.observeTasks().distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { filterTasks(it) }` to return the latest result?

2: I don't know how `distinctUntilChanged()` work, will it keep listening to return the latest result in whole Lifecycle ?

3: What's happened if I use `tasksRepository.observeTasks().switchMap { filterTasks(it) }` instead of `tasksRepository.observeTasks().distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { filterTasks(it) }`

**Code**

```
class TasksViewModel(..) : ViewModel() {    
    private val _items: LiveData<List<Task>> = _forceUpdate.switchMap { forceUpdate ->
        if (forceUpdate) {
            _dataLoading.value = true
            viewModelScope.launch {
                tasksRepository.refreshTasks()
                _dataLoading.value = false
            }
        }
        tasksRepository.observeTasks().distinctUntilChanged().switchMap { filterTasks(it) }
    }
   
   ...
}


class DefaultTasksRepository(...) : TasksRepository {  

    override suspend fun refreshTask(taskId: String) {
        updateTaskFromRemoteDataSource(taskId)
    }

    private suspend fun updateTasksFromRemoteDataSource() {
        val remoteTasks = tasksRemoteDataSource.getTasks()

        if (remoteTasks is Success) {
            tasksLocalDataSource.deleteAllTasks()
            remoteTasks.data.forEach { task ->
                tasksLocalDataSource.saveTask(task)
            }
        } else if (remoteTasks is Result.Error) {
            throw remoteTasks.exception
        }
    }

    override fun observeTasks(): LiveData<Result<List<Task>>> {
        return tasksLocalDataSource.observeTasks()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `switchMap` - The returned LiveData delegates to the most recent LiveData created by calling switchMapFunction with the most recent value set to source, without changing the reference. [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#switchMap(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E))
2. Yes, it'll keep listening to return the latest result in whole Lifecycle. `distinctUntilChanged` creates a new LiveData object that does not emit a value until the source LiveData value has been changed. The value is considered changed if `equals()` yields `false`.
3. Yes you can use that too but it'll keep emitting the values even the values are the same as the last emitted value.
   e.g. first emitted value is ["aman","bansal"] and the second is the same ["aman","bansal"] which you don't want to emit since the values are same. So you use `distinctUntilChanged` to make sure it won't emit the same value until changed.

I hope this helped.